# Does Jquery Mobile Framework Help Web Developer

Tags: android, asp.net, ios, mobile, jquery-mobile

I am .net developer. I want to develop an application for mobile devices. As i am a web developer i am well versed with web technology & scripting languages. I am a big fan of JQuery so, i found something Jquery Mobile Framework for mobile application development.

So, I've got few questions:

1. Will this framework help me develop web applications or only for designing purpose?
2. Can i use my Jquery knowledge to implement web application using Jquery Mobile Framework?
3. Can i use Jquery AJAX in mobile app development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. jQuery Mobile will help you build a website, you can then view that website in a browser or package it into an app. If you want to create native applications out of HTML/CSS/JS then you will need an intermediary step that lets you run a webview as your app. [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) is an example of a framework that allows you to use native APIs while building your application in HTML/CSS/JS.
2. Your knowledge of jQuery will come-in handy but you will be forced to think about a jQuery Mobile website differently. For instance, pages are not HTML documents, but `pseudo-pages` that can be in separate documents but can also have multiple `pseudo-pages` inside a single HTML document. And because remote documents are brought into the DOM via AJAX (for animated transitions), you need to code your site to use unique IDs across the whole site, not just from page to page.
3. Absolutely! jQuery AJAX makes creating dynamic websites and native apps easy. You basically just load a bunch of views (in HTML/JS/CSS) into the app. package and then your server does the modeling. One cool thing to take into consideration is that since you are running from a mobile app., there is no domain from which the response is sent, so there is no cross-domain-policy to worry about.

If you have not yet checked-out [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/), do so, and also see the [documentation on the jQuery Mobile website](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/phonegap.html) regarding how to create [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) applications using jQuery Mobile:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/phonegap.html

Answer (score 3):

It won't help you build a mobile "application" but it will help you create a mobile enabled web site.

1. It will help you build the front end of a mobile web application.
2. Yes
3. Yes, if you are referring to mobile **web** applications.

The back-end technology you use does not matter. I've built several .NET MVC sites using jQuery Mobile, which have all worked pretty well.

Comment: It should be pointed out that answer 3 is generally only possible with another framework, such as PhoneGap (I'm assuming the poster is referring to native apps)

Comment: good point, I have updated number 3 to indicate that it only applies to web apps.

Comment: jQuery Mobile helps build UIs, which is essential to building a native application, so it seems that `it will help you build a mobile "application"`.